# How to make a bot reply depending on the ping? (text message)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and I want to add a feature when I use the command `_throw` and ping a user, the bot will reply depending on the user ping (It's preferred to be a usual text message, **not** embed). Currently, I have this code:

```py
if message.content == "_throw":
    user = message.mentions[0]
    await message.channel.send("You threw a hamster to " + f"{user}" + "!")
```

But my bot doesn't reply to it at all (PyCharm doesn't see any error).

Here's my bot script:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('_hi'):
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello, {message.author.mention}!')

    if message.content == "_throw":
        user = message.mentions[0]
        await message.channel.send("You threw hamster to " + f"{user}" + "!")

    if message.content.startswith("_userinfo"):
        user = message.mentions[0]
        emb14 = discord.Embed(
            title=f"@{user} info:",
            colour=discord.Colour.dark_blue()
        )
        emb14.set_image(url=user.avatar_url)
        emb14.add_field(name=f"Name", value=f"{user}", inline=True)
        emb14.add_field(name=f"Discord Joined date", value=f"{user.created_at}", inline=False)
        emb14.add_field(name=f"Server Joined date", value=f"{user.joined_at}", inline=False)
        emb14.add_field(name="Profile Picture", value=":arrow_down: :arrow_down: ", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=emb14)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238509/discussion-between-aaron-and-taku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want your bot to respond to `_throw @user`. In this case, when you check `message.content == "_throw"`, it's filtering the messages that's exactly `_throw` and not the `@user` part.

To accept a user mention argument, the simplest method would to use a regex match:

```
import re

# First checks if there are any mentions in the message
# Then uses regex "^_throw\s+<@!?[0-9]{17,22}>$" to match the message content
if message.mentions and re.match(r"^_throw\s+<@!?[0-9]{17,22}>$", message.content):
    user = message.mentions[0]
    await message.channel.send(f"You threw a hamster to {user.mention)!")
```

This will allow the bot to reply to `_throw @user` and responds with `You threw a hamster to @user!`

Comment: Thank you really much! It works! But I have one question: What is `\s+<@!?[0-9]{17,22}>$`?

Comment: Its a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) and is used to match patterns. The one I wrote means: starts with 1 or more spaces, followed by "<", then optionally followed by "!", followed by 17-22 digits, and ends with ">". Together it'll match Discord's user mention, such as: "<@!357449931555471605>" (which is the actual message stored in @user).

Comment: Thank you! One last question: How do you make a code, when I mention myself in the `_throw` command, the bot will reply: `Woah, you threw hamster to yourself` or `You can't throw things at urself lol`?

Comment: @Aaron You can add an if statement to check `if user == message.author`, and write your desired outputs in the if and else blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But when I added your code (`if user == message.author`), the bot replies both with the `_throw` command and `You can't throw things at urself`. It seems that bot firstly replies with `You threw hamster to @Me` and then `You can't throw things at urself`. How to make a bot send only 1 message - You can't throw things at urself, if I mention myself?

Comment: @Aaron Hello, as I mentioned before, you'll need an if-else block. In the if part you can have `await message.channel.send(f"You threw a hamster to yourself!")` and the else with `await message.channel.send(f"You threw a hamster to {user.mention)!")` so only one message gets sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238552/discussion-between-aaron-and-taku).